# What SQL functions do I use in PhpMyAdmin to extract only orders that are overtime?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, phpmyadmin

I'm currently starting off learning SQL in PhpAdmin, and I got stuck with this question.
It's about a small database representing a videostore (kind of outdated, I know)

**The question:**
Give all data on orders from which the deadline has expired and are not returned in time.
CASE: Deadline for return is one day after rent at 22:00:00.

*--> The main issue here is that I don't know how to set/calculate a deadline or something here.*

Note that my start_date = DATETIME

The database structure looks kinda like this:

**VIDEOSTORE**

| tl_dvd | tl_genre | tl_client | tl_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| title | name | first_name | client_id |
| release_date | min_age | last_name | dvd_id |
| origin_country | description |  | *start_date* |
| duration |  |  |  |
| genre_id |  |  |  |

This is as far as I get myself, then try some shit into errors and erase.

```
SELECT * FROM tl_order WHERE /*start_date (DATETIME) ; to deadline = (nextday, 22:00:00)*/
```

Some things I've looked into so far: DATEDIFF, DATEADD,... What function(s) should I use?

Many thanks in advance!

Ricky

Comment: You don't seem to have a way of identifying returned items

Comment: whats the column for deadline?

Comment: Something like `WHERE return_date > DATE(rent_date) + INTERVAL 46 HOUR`

Comment: @Akina I'll be sure to look into that INTERVAL function thanks!

Comment: @eshirvana I think I should just calculate this from start_date, since the date is always different? YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS to YYYY-MM-DD+1 at 22:00:00

Comment: If you looked at datediff you should already be familiar with interval btw its DATE_ADD in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: *I'll be sure to look into that INTERVAL function* INTERVAL is not a function. This is datatype operator. INTERVAL() function performs absolutely another operation which is not related to datetime.

Comment: @Akina I tend to switch the names a lot... thanks for clearing this out!

Comment: @P.Salmon I'll be sure to remember that documentation site, didn't come across it yet and it looks great.

Answer (score -1):

ok then your query should look like this for checking the expiration datetime , but not sure how you check if it is not returned, I can't figure out based on your info

```
SELECT * FROM tl_order o
JOIN tl_client c on c.id = o.client_id
JOIN tl_dvd d on d.id = o.dvd_id
WHERE 
  o.start_date <= colleasce(DATE(return_date),CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 22 HOUR
```

first, condition finds the ones that they have NOT returned their dvd yet but they have passed their deadline .

second, checks if the ones that returned their dvd late (after their deadline)

Comment: Why do you deal with the current date? We need rent date and return date. Nothing to do with now date :)

Comment: @AntonMitsev then how do you know it's been expired?! think more about it

Comment: please look at @Akina comment above. Mine too – `rent_date` and `return_date`. You may have items taken last week and return in time. The question is not saying all the ordered not returned. Or is it?

Comment: This is very interesting to work on, thank you. Some of the orders in my data are returned, others are not. I need to subtract which aren't or are too late returned.

Comment: But i see, indeed we have no need for the current date

Comment: @Rix11 hmmm.. then does it mean you have a column for "returndate" ? because if you have a returndate is still empty for those who have not returned their dvd it means you still need to compare with today's date